# REGEX in GA view filter (search and replace) to output a numeric ID from URI

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I'd like to search and replace in Google Analytics view filter all my Request URIs in such a way that just the article id remains (plus, to add an "a-" before the ID).

Example URIs:

```
/raksts/sievietem/281750-ilona-balode-par-dzivi-ar-udriti-no-mums-beg-ka-no-grimstosa-kuga

/raksts/zinas/281427-video-izskatas-ka-spelu-automatu-atkariba-baibu-strautmani-nelaiz-vala

/raksts/arzemes/282070-pasauli-savilno-mazas-princeses-sarlotes-emocijas-karaliskajas-kazas

/raksts/izklaide/280379-turpinas-tirisana-jrt-maru-kimeli-atlaiz-hermana-sieva-aiziet-pati
```

The result I'm after:

```
a-281750

a-281427

a-282070

a-280379
```

In Regex checking sites it works like a charm, Regex being:

```
\/raksts\/\D+(\d+).+
```

Substitution being:

```
a-$1
```

But when I apply them to a GA filter, the checker tells me that the filter wouldn't have changed any data.

Not sure if I need to do this in GA - Data Studio would do too, the endgame being exported article IDs for our IT guys to implement in our editorial interface through Google API.

Probably a dumb question for which I apologize, but I feel quite stuck, so even a hint in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need to match the whole string? `.*raksts/\D+(\d+).*`?

Comment: Thanks, it made some difference - now the verifier at least shows something. I'm inclined to think that it's not really the right thing though - here's a screenshot of GA verifier results from your line:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XKcm2gTkUVPfYCevslWxn5fgpCVkIs1n

And here's my line it working properly in a regexr: https://regexr.com/3qe8n

Am I missing something? Does GA use a different language from what those regex helpers do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add backslash before 1:

a-\1